# Difference between declaring variables like &ref=a and ref=&a in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, variable-declaration

I'm little confused about two types of i came across like if int a=0, what does it "&ref=a" refers to and what "ref=&a" this thing refers to?

do these serves the same purpose of holding address of variable?

Comment: Those are not complete declarations. I assume you mean `int &ref = a;` and `int *ref = &a;`. The difference is the first one is a reference to `a` and the second one is a pointer to `a`. Similar but very different things. A pointer contains a memory address, yes. A reference is just an alias to the thing it refers to, but it is *commonly* implemented using a pointer in most compilers.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what `&ref = a;` and `ref = &a;` are referring to. I suspect it is as @RemyLebeau suggests above. Also when you edit, if you encluse the code portions in *back ticks*, e.g. `\`` -- it will format in fixed width.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&ref=a` : It is the reference variable means it's is the another name for existing variable. It can be used like normal variables.Memory management of references left up to compiler

`*ref=&a` : It is the pointer  variable it holds the address of another variable. Pointers are used to store and manage the addresses of dynamically allocated blocks of memory.

And the my answer is YES, Both should  serves the same purpose in holding variable because in most compilers the reference can thought as constant pointer itself.

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
int a=10;
int &ref=a;
std::cout<<ref;
```

it will print 10

```
int a=10;
int *ref=&a;
std::cout<<ref;
```

it will print address of a, if you want value you should put like this `*ref` that is you should dereference it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

void fun(int &var)
{
    var=100;
}

int main()
{
    int a=10;
    fun(a);    //no need & here
    std::cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

and see this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

void fun(int *var)
{
    *var=100;
}

int main()
{
    int a=10;
    fun(&a);    //need & here
    std::cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but needs more explanation of what's happening and why to be a good answer.